# Re-reading CSV method for bufferedSource

Tags: scala

I'm trying to read a csv and gather two types of informations.

I need to read it once to get the number of lines that my csv contains.
I need to go back to the top of the csv and re read it again to retrieve the values.
I'm looking for something similar to seek(0) in java for bufferedSource
I've tried to close and re open the buffer but I think I'm overthiking it.
I also read through the source library but nothing came close to what I'm looking for.

PS:I know this is not optimized however my first read will basically enable me to create an array to store the values I'd retrive from the second read(and not a list).

I would take any clue you might have to offer !

Thanks a lot

Comment: You might start with a CSV processing library. You don't want to do this yourself.

Comment: Why not just `.fromFile("...").getLines().toArray`?

Comment: I will look into the option suggested above. And I must do it on my own which means no spark scala and such..